# Continuity of the eigenvalues.

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I came across a statement of which I do not understand the meaning.

> The smallest eigenvalue of a $k \times k$ symmetric matrix $M$, $\inf_{ \{v \in R^k | ||v|| = 1 \} } v'Mv$, is continuous in $M$.

What does it mean to be continuous in $M$, and why do we have $\inf_{ \{v \in R^k | ||v|| = 1 \} } v'Mv$?

If you do not want to go in to the details a reference to study is sufficient for me.

Comment: $\inf_{v\in R^n, \|v\|_2=1}v'Mv$ comes from the **Rayleigh quotient** associated to $M$

Comment: Moreover, Peter Lax [states in his book](http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Its-Applications-Peter/dp/0471751561): if $M_t\to M$ as $t\to 0$ and $\lambda_1(t),\ldots,\lambda_k(t)$ are the eigenvalues of $M_T$, then $\{\lambda_1(t),\ldots,\lambda_k(t)\}\to\{\lambda_1(0),\ldots,\lambda_k(0)\}$ as $t\to 0$. This might be your continuity result.

Comment: Any hint about what that v' means?

Comment: @Dohleman $v'$ is the (conjugate) transpose of the vector $v$.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207452/eigenvectors-as-continuous-functions-of-matrix-diagonal-perturbations/207833#207833

Comment: Continuous in $M$ means precisely that: it is a continuous function of the matrix $M$.  For this purpose, $M$ is thought of as an element of a $k(k+1)/2$-dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

*What does it mean to be continuous in M, and why do we have $\inf_{v \in R^k\ |\ ||v||=1}v′Mv$ ?*

Continuous in $M$ means that the eigenvalue in question changes only a little if you change any element of the matrix $M$ by just a little. There is a formal definition in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ but the above is the gist of it.

The need for $v \in R^k\ |\ ||v||=1$ comes from the fact that any scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector so you only need to look at eigenvectors of norm 1. Now, if $v$ is such an eigenvector then $v'Mv = v'(Mv) = v'(\lambda v) = \lambda v'v = \lambda\,||v||^2 = \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue associated with the eigenvector $v$.

Thus, $\inf_{v \in R^k\ |\ ||v||=1}v′Mv$ just means "the smallest eigenvector of $M$" because it's looking at the smallest value of $\lambda$ for all possible eigenvectors $v$ of norm 1.

Comment: This does not show that the critical points of the function $R(v)=v'Mv/\|v\|_2^2$ are the eigenvectors of $M$ and the associated critical value is the associated eigenvalue. This is, in facts, the real explanation for the fact that $\inf_{v\in\Bbb R^n}R(v)$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $M$. As already suggested in my comment. This fact is well known and the function $R$ has even a name: [Rayleigh quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient).

Comment: _This does not show that the critical points of the function $R(v)$ are the eigenvectors of $M$ and the associated critical value is the associated eigenvalue_ - No, it doesn't, which is why I qualified my response with "if $v$ is such an eigenvector". The way I see it, if the OP doesn't quite understand the notion of continuity in this context then throwing the Rayleigh quotient at him/her is not going to be very helpful, so I was aiming for a mote intuitive explanation.